# How do I get a url '/relationships/new?followed_id=bob' to instead read 'relationships/new/bob'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, routes, url-routing, parameters

So, I have a search bar so a user(adam) can search for another user(bob)

- The search bar searches for users based on name. (search 'bob' returns 'bob') (this happens on users/index.html.erb)
- Once the user is found their name is displayed, and an 'add relationship' button appears next to the search result. 
  (bob 'add relationship')(again this pops up on users/index.html.erb)
- I want the 'add relationship' button to link to a page: 'relationships/new/bob' (relationships/new/friendname)
- at the moment it links to /relationships/new?followed_id=bob

**any ideas how i get '/relationships/new?followed_id=bob' to become 'relationships/new/bob'?**

**is it a case of sending in a different param or variable so the search returns 'bob' instead of '?followed_id=bob'?

**or, is it possible to send the name param of the person being searching in with the search result so it can be linked to the 'add relationship' button when it's pressed?**

(other relevant info, has_many and has_many through relationships are all set up correctly so a user has_many relationships, to_params is also set in the users model, I don't believe the answer will have anything to do with these aspects)

**users_controller:**

```
  def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
    @followed = User.find_by(name: params[:search])
    # @followed = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
  end
```

**users/index.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <li>
            <%= user.name %>
            <%= link_to "Add Relationship", new_relationship_path(followed_id: @followed), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <%= @followed %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

**relationships_controller:**

```
  def new
    if params[:followed_id]
      # @followed = User.find_by(name: params[:followed_id])
      # @followed = User.find(params[:followed_id])
      # @followed = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @followed.nil?
      @active_relationship = current_user.active_relationships.new(followed: @followed)
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Relationship required"
    end

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
    render 'public/404', status: :not_found
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well then you need a collection route to do that (I saw an answer like this 3 months ago, when I started rails), with a little hack:

```
resources :users do
 collection do
   get :search, action: "search_user",  as: "search_user"
   get 'search/:followed_id', action: "search", as: "search"
 end
end
```

and then you can have a function in your `users_controller` named `search_user` which would

`redirect_to search_users_path(params[:followed_id])`

This can also be done with JavaScript by modifying the `window.href` but there is a gem available called,
[js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes), which can help you with that, without the routes and controller hassle.

It seems you wanted to use user's name instead of something unique, like an `id` or something, but the approach has a flaw, what if there are more than users with same name.

This is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/argentum47/9047b5e7c6c7db3e6cf6) of what your code should conventionally look like. I didn't test it though.

Comment: So option 1: set up collection routes or option 2: use JavaScript or option 3: look into js-routes?

Comment: if you ask me about priorities, personally "i am living a gem life", so since a gem is tested you can opt for a gem than using JS directly, And yeah those are or's . After you check the gem, maybe you can decide which one to use. If you don't need route modifications else where then  you can use the routing.

Comment: i don't think i need this elsewhere - maybe the routing (option 1?) option? I'm not sure how to implement option 1 though - can we chat?

Comment: what is there to chat in this :P , check out if the routing works then do it. I wrote the code. Still if you feel you need help, initiate the chat.

Comment: i don't understand how your answer helps me solve the problem I have, I was hoping for clarity on how it all works. (also how does one start a chat?)

Comment: and also @argentum47 how does it connect to the view and integrate with what is already set up?

Comment: actually i presume when you said controller you meant view? I get 'No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"users", :follower_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:follower_id]' and I'm not sure why you mention follower_id instead of followed_id?

Comment: ah, my mistake, but the error is saying you what it is, you need params[:folower_id] instead of followed_id.

Comment: It's only saying that because I added your code in which introduced follower_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64766/discussion-between-argentum47-and-sss333).